# Data inaccuracy problem with lookup and deleted/unavailable record

Tags: lookup, data, insufficient-privileges

I am facing strange problem. We have lookup on Product object which refers to product group. When we query or view product we can see the ID of product group but not name as it happens in case of normal lookup field.

When we access this field in code we get "Insufficient access error"

My question is why its behaving like this? Ideally it should delete the reference of id in lookup when the parent record is deleted?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens mostly in partial copy sandbox but can happen in full copy sandbox as well

Those records are called as Ghost records. We know there is a limit of 10k records or 5GB worth of records in [partial copy sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206556&type=1).

So in your case, Salesforce only cloned the child record but did not copy the parent record and hence it cannot populate that record's field and you dont see its name in the UI.

There is [an Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxuMAAQ) to maintain the referential integrity of the data, ie when child is copied parent should also be copied and not any random 10 k rows.

More can be read here : http://stephenscholtz.com/201702/partial-copy-sandboxes-ghost-dad